# JFX TableMenu context menu label empty

Tags: javafx, tableview, contextmenu

I wanted to add textfields to individual columns to allow individual column filtering. But after applying the following code, the table menu button on the top right corner when clicked, only displays 4 ticks(I have 4 columns), the label is missing. I assume this is because the header now is no longer just a label, but label with textfields. Anyone have a solution to this?

```
TextField headerTextField = new TextField();
Label label = new Label("First Name");
VBox headerGraphic = new VBox();
headerGraphic.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
headerGraphic.getChildren().addAll(label, headerTextField);

TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new 
TableColumn<>();
firstNameCol.setGraphic(headerGraphic);
```

Comment: maybe you can try to add your 2 elements in a HBox, and add the HBox to your display. (Just to give it a try) Btw, does the column accept adding a VBox as a "Graphic"?

Comment: Yeah VBox seems to work fine.. the filter etc all works fine.. just when I thought I'm done when I tried clicking on the menu button to hide a column, I was shocked to see all text labels missing

Comment: _I assume this is because the header now is no longer just a label_ wrong assumption in several ways ;) a) the header never is just a label (in fact it contains a label but that's a hidden implemenation detail) b) the menu isn't showing the text because the column's text property value is empty. Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, setting the ContentDisplay of the (contained) header label such that the graphic is shown below the text might do the trick.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the clarification, but I'm not exactly sure what do u mean by setting the graphic below the text. Currently my column label is above the filter textfields. As for what I wish to achieve, I'm hoping the column text property is the name of the column, so that I know which column I'm actually hiding from the context menu.

Comment: I did column.setText("Header1") and yes context menu shows Header1, but the text header1 also shows on the table header, which isn't what I need since I already had the proper label and textfields graphic set.

Comment: yeah sure, the text is shown by the default header, what else do you expect ;) Remove your custom label (will not be updated when changing the text, anyway) and only have the textfield as graphic ..

Comment: Ah I see what u mean! You mean to use set text for the label and add the textfields below the text.. great idea! But again, I'm unfamiliar and unsure how to achieve that. :/